# Cannot connect to rabbitmq message broker in flask-celery application

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have created a flask application to process GNSS data. There are certain functions which takes a lot of time to execute. Therefore i have integrated celery to perform those functions as Asynchronous tasks. First I have tested the app in localhost by adding message broker as rabbitmq

```
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']='amqp://localhost//'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND']='db+postgresql://username:pssword@localhost/DBname'
```

After fully tested the application in virtualenv I deployed It on heroku and added rabbitmq addon. Then I changed the `app.config` as follows.

```
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']='amqp://myUsername:Mypassowrd@small-fiver-23.bigwig.lshift.net:10123/FlGJwZfbz4TR'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND']='db+postgres://myusername:Mypassword@ec2-54-163-246-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dhcbl58v8ifst/MYDB'
```

After changing the above I ran the celery worker

```
celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info
```

and get this error

```
[2018-03-16 11:21:16,796: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://SHt1Xvhb:**@small-fiver-23.bigwig.lshift.net:10123/FlGJwZfbz4TR: timed out.
```

How can I check whether my heroku addon is working from Rabbitmq management console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the port 10123 is not exposed. Can you try `telnet small-fiver-23.bigwig.lshift.net 10123` from the server and see if you're able to connect successfully to the server?

If not, you have to expose that port to be accessible from the server you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @bharathI our office wifi has blocked that port so I connected with a seperate wifi connection and it worked. Thanks for the input